# Show one div class in body at the time

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show a `div` at a time called li. but when I come to the div that has the class `three`, everything stops. I can not skip the `div` and continue to show the `div` with class second

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4N3M/5/)

```
<div class="second current">
<button class="show">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="second">
<button class="show">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="second">
<button class="show">Show</button>
</div>
```

// the jQuery stops here

```
<div class="three">

</div>


<div class="second">
<button class="show">Show</button>
</div>



</body>



<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      //$(".second").hide();

      $(".show").click(function(){
          $(this).hide();

        $(".second.current").next(".second").addClass("current");
        //$('.second').next().show();
      });


    });
```

When I click I want to only show one `div` with the class `second`, not the last one.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4N3M/5/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to show a div at a time called "second". but when I come to the div that has the class name "three" then everything stops. I want to skip the div with class name "three" and continue to show the div with the class name "second"

Comment: i cant show the last div with class name "second" after the div with the class name "three".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.next()` only finds the *immediately* following sibling, so it does not continue the process when it hits the class `.three`. You may try the following:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B4N3M/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //$(".second").hide();

  $(".show").click(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      var currentElement = $(".second.current").last();
      currentElement.nextAll(".second").first().addClass("current");
  });


});
```